# Fabric Native Component throwing error in build folder PackageList.java file error: cannot find symbol import com.rtncenteredtext.CenteredTextPackage;

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-bridge

I have tried fabric native components as given in https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/the-new-architecture/pillars-fabric-components?fabric-component-specs=flow&android-language=kotlin for android. And it is throwing error following.

> MyFabricApp/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
> import com.rtncenteredtext.CenteredTextPackage;
> ^
> symbol:   class CenteredTextPackage
> location: package com.rtncenteredtext
> MyFabricApp/android/app/build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
> new CenteredTextPackage()
> ^
> symbol:   class CenteredTextPackage
> location: class PackageList
> 2 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset cache and run app again, that will solve this issue

```
npm start --reset-cache
```